# Can you define functions in a JEXL Script?

Tags: java, jexl

A JEXL Script is not the same as a JEXL Expression.

I see references to functions in the source code, but I see no documentation about it. Has it maybe not been implemented yet?

There is a JSR-223 interface for it.

Comment: I would also really like to know! Good question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to defined functions, then you should use the JexlEngine#setFunctions(Map namespace2FunctorMap). See the [Javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/jexl/apidocs/index.html) (currently down ;-( )

If you need methods, then you should add to your JexlContext the objects having the methods you want to call. See "calling methods" in [this page](http://commons.apache.org/jexl/reference/examples.html#Example_Expressions).

Under the hood, Jexl uses reflection to call methods if I can properly remember.

Comment: Neat. So that allows you to define top-level functions. It's like static import in Java. I think I was trying to see if you can write the function code in JEXL, not just call a function or method written in Java.

Comment: I don't think that Jexl currently allows defining new functions in a script.

You could trick it by preprossessing your file to extract the functions code, wrap it into Java objects and register them to the engine.